# SpringWeb Jmustache and @DateTimeFormat

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, mustache

I have a spring boot application using server-side Mustache-Templates (JMustache).

A simple Bean with an `@DateTimeFormat`-Annotation:

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

public class GeneralInformation {


    private Date serverTime = new Date();

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd.MM.yyyy")
    public Date getServerTime() {
        return serverTime;
    }

    public void setServerTime(Date serverTime) {
        this.serverTime = serverTime;
    }
}
```

A simple controller adding the bean to the model:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class RootController {
    // some Autowiring stuff here...

    @RequestMapping(value="")
    public String index(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("generalInformation", new GeneralInformation());
        return "hello";
    }   
}
```

And my Server-Side Mustache-template stored under `templates/hello.html`

```
<p>Servertime: {{generalInformation.serverTime}}</p>
```

When using JSP's the output of the date is formatted after the pattern used in the `@DateTimeFormat`-Annotation but not when using my Mustache-Template.

I could format the date in the `@Controller`-Annotated-Method and store it as a `String` in the Bean, but that doesn't seem to be a good way.

Does anybody know, if it is possible to make JMustache aware of the Validation-Tags?

How else could I achieve Formatting when using JMustache together with SpringMVC?

Answer (score -1):

@DateTimeFormat only works with JSP

Comment: Yep, I know that. But this wasn't my question. I asked how I could get a simliar behaviour when NOT using JSP's.